# Separate scrap and production by area

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm looking for feedback on things that can be streamlined in each section. The data it creates is all needed whether it's used in a graph or not so I can't get rid of anything, just combine steps maybe.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\eb2547\\Desktop\\python code for work\\2017 TB.csv")

# Scrap separation
noNan = data[['Quantity','Scrap Cause']].dropna()
scrap = noNan.groupby('Scrap Cause').sum()


# Hanging production
hangdata = data[(data['Transaction Description'].str.contains('INVM') == True) &
                (data['Location No'] == 'SF HANK STAGING')]
hangprod = hangdata['Quantity'].sum()


# Tapered production


# Wrapper production
wrapdatatobug = data[(data['Transaction Description'] == 'INVM-ISS') &
                (data['Location No'].str.contains('BUG') == True)]
wrapprodtobug = wrapdatatobug['Quantity'].sum()
wrapdatatobox = data[(data['Transaction Description'] == 'OOREC') &
                     (data['Location No'].str.contains('BOX ASSEMBLY-WRAP') == True)]
wrapprodtobox = wrapdatatobox['Quantity'].sum()
wrapscrap = data[(data['Scrap Cause'].str.contains('W') == True)]
wrapscraptotal = wrapscrap['Quantity'].sum()
wrapprodtotal = wrapprodtobug + wrapprodtobox

# Cut Piece production
cpdata = data[(data['Transaction Description'] == 'OOREC') &
               (data['Location No'].str.contains('BOX ASSEMBLY-CP') == True)]
cpprod = cpdata['Quantity'].sum()
cpscrap = data[(data['Scrap Cause'].str.contains('C') == True)]
cpscraptotal = cpscrap['Quantity'].sum()

# Graphs of scrap data
wrapscrap2 = scrap[(scrap.index.str.contains('W') == True)]
cpscrap2 = scrap[(scrap.index.str.contains('C') == True)]
spinscrap = scrap[(scrap.index).str.contains('S') == True]
def Wrap_Scrap():
    fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
    sns.barplot(data=wrapscrap2,x=wrapscrap2.index,y='Quantity')
def CP_Scrap():
    fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
    sns.barplot(data=cpscrap2,x=cpscrap2.index,y='Quantity')

# Graph of production
prodoverview = pd.DataFrame([hangprod,wrapprodtotal,cpprod],
                            index=['Hanging','Wrapping','CP'],
                            columns=['Quantity'])
def Prod_Graph():
    fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
    sns.barplot(data=prodoverview,x=prodoverview.index,y='Quantity')
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to explain what this code is supposed to do, please? It is hard to review code unless we know what problem it is supposed to solve.

Comment: @GarethRees it takes the data frame which is a 95,000 row 16 column excel sheet, in the scrap cause column there are about 30-40 different reasons, breaks them all down by grouping them and summing them. Then in the rest of it it breaks down different areas by specific scrap code and makes them into graphs or just variables for me to look at.

Comment: Normally you'd do that kind of thing directly in Excel — you can group and sum rows by categories using a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576), and draw graphs using [pivot charts](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-PivotChart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c). Can you edit the post to explain why this didn't work for you?

Comment: @GarethRees it did work, just want to know if there are steps I can combine. Also I do this in excel normally, started working on this to just see if I could with programming and it worked, now I’m looking for improvements. I do a lot of very advanced work in excel to the point that I thought I might enjoy programming so I started learning it, and I do enjoy it.

Comment: Do you have a bit of sample data and expected outcome for this data? This can make it a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

## efficiency

Overall, the code looks idiomatic and sensible, no major issues. But you want to tweak it for efficiency. Here are some things you might try.

Most importantly, instrument elapsed time, so you can tell if a tweak is useful:

```
    t0 = time.time()
    ...
    elapsed = time.time() - t0
```

And definitely [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-script#582337) the [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), so you know where to focus your efforts.

Ok, with that in hand, it looks like you need to synthesize some boolean columns. There are several columns that you repeatedly inspect, e.g. Transaction Description. Perhaps you could add them to the spreadsheet, to avoid repeatedly processing unchanging data? Another approach would be to build up a list of rows and then do `data = pd.DataFrame(rows)`. This would let you examine each Transaction Description once and derive a couple of columns. But frankly, I'm skeptical this would improve your timings at all, the code looks fine as is.

## style

Do use a pep8 linter: [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), and follow its advice.

In hard-to-read identifiers like `spinscrap`, introduce an underscore so it is clear to the Gentle Reader where word breaks are.